# Unable to override a module's admin controller in Prestashop 1.7.7.2

Tags: module, controller, overriding, prestashop-1.7

I created a module and I want to override an admin controller from an existing module. I created the override folder using the path `modules/mymodule/override/modules/marketplace/controllers/admin/AdminSellerProductDetailController.php` following https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/ but it does not seem to copy into the `/override/` folder. I've reinstalled the module, deleted the cache, but nothing seems to work.

Couldn't find any solutions anywhere else online, so your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue? What is displayed after debug mode is on ?

Comment: The override folder should be placed in the module directory, not in override directory.
The override should be `modules/mymodule/override/controllers/admin/AdminSellerProductDetailController.php`.
What is `modules/marketplace`??